# Can someone show me how to write a bot in python that deletes itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for some reason I thought this idea was interesting, its probably quite simple but I don't know how I would go about it. I want to write a bot that has some form of question prompt and after the given question prompt is answered the bot just deletes its own code and dies >:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__file__` is the path of the file currently being executed, so you can delete it with:

```py
import os
os.remove(__file__)
```

Comment: `import time
import os
x = input("Kill Me:D! ".title())
if x == "yes":
    print("Goodbye.")
    time.sleep(3)
    os.remove('Useless Bot.ipynb')
else:
        print("type yes".title())
while x != "yes":
    x = input("Kill Me:D! ".title())
    if x == "yes":
        print("Goodbye.")
        time.sleep(3)
        os.remove('Useless Bot.ipynb')
    else:
            print("Type Yes")`